# How to limit items/row in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC-application I have a class with some properties. In the .cshtml-file I loop through
these properties like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeID)
        </td>
```

This works fine and I get a list of all the objects I loop through.  I would like to limit the nr of items per column in order to avoid having to scroll down. Lets say that I want 5 items/row lined up next to each-other instead of a long list. 
Could I maybe create 2 equal divs side by side and have my list fill upp the first one and then the other?

[image]

Comment: You should append a number (ITEM1, ITEM2, ... , ITEMn) to make it clear how you'd like them to be layed out

Comment: this question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748783/how-can-i-loop-through-my-table-to-display-contents-side-by-side-in-mvc-razor-vi